# Spring webflux - Validate Query param & Path param

Tags: spring-webflux

Is there any better way to do query param validation in Spring webflux handler?

```
final Optional<String> productIdParam = request.queryParam("product_id");
        int productId = 0;
        if(!productIdParam.isEmpty()) {
            productId = Integer.parseInt(productIdParam.get());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not with the 'functional' definition.
You could switch to  definition with controllers and annotations which gives you validation of `PathVariable`'s, `RequestParam`'s and the `RequestBody` out of the box.

[Take a look at the Spring Webflux docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-controller)